# delegated jQuery .on() not working for SharePoint Web Part

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint-Webpart with a table containing many elements.
If I click on an element I see a preview of the document behind it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-itmhover").on("click", showPreview);
});
```

the problem is, if I sort the table it reloads the elements an the click-event is removed.
So i tried a delegatet .on() function

```
jQuery("table.ms-listviewtable").on("click", "tr.ms-itmhover", showPreview);
```

but if I click nothing happens.. I also tried

```
jQuery(document.body).on("click", "table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-itmhover", showPreview);
```

so that i have the same selector as in the not delegated (and working) function, but it is also not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The delegated handler should work. Have you checked the console for errors? What is the content of your `showPreview()` function? Are you sure it's not being called?

Comment: It could be that your table is loaded dynamically too. If it's the case, try handling the event from the document: `jQuery(document).on("click", "table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-itmhover", showPreview);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I checked it, there are no errors. And if i enter the code in the console the table selector returns the right object, but is still not working. The showPreview function is just to show the document. I debugged it and it's not called. I also tried `jQuery("table.ms-listviewtable").on("click", "tr.ms-itmhover", function() { alert("test"); });` to test it, but nothing happen. The strange thing is that the not delegated function is working if I enter it in the console after sorting the table the preview is working fine until the next sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, crazy SharePoint..

It works if i use "mouseup" instead of "click" as event.

```
jQuery("table.ms-listviewtable").on("mouseup", "tr.ms-itmhover", showPreview);
```